# Unable to understand Verilog syntax

Tags: verilog, hardware, hdl, system-verilog

I found an example Verilog code as following:

```
module test #(parameter p=1) ();
    localparam [1:0] lp = ~(p)'(1'b0);
endmodule
```

I'm unable to undestand the **localparam** `lp` assignment.
Can you please explain the code?

Comment: You may find this verilog reference guide useful: http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange example, not sure what this example was intended to do. There's only the `module` declaration and a `localparam` declaration, nothing else.

Defines a module which is named test, which has no input nor output ports (because the port list is an empty set of parenthesis). However it does take a single parameter named p (this is inside the hash-parenthesis list `#(p)` part of the `module` declaration ). The default value of the parameter p is 1 unless otherwise specified.

Inside the definition of the module, there is another parameter declared, which is named lp, which is defined as the constant expression `~(p)'(1'b0)`.

The unary `~` is the bitwise negation operator, and the literal integer expression `(p)'(1'b0)` is a constant that is "p" number of bits wide, and all of the bits are 0.  So `~(p)'(1'b0)` is all bits 1.  Note in verilog, we always care exactly about the bit width of every constant, wire, and net; literal constants use that infix apostrophe `'` to indicate the bit width.

This is a very strange example, because with no ports and nothing making any use of the parameters, there's nothing for a simulator or an HDL compiler to do.

Usually verilog modules have input and output ports, with the exception of a test bench that is used to simulate and test other modules. But that's not the case here, because this module doesn't instantiate any other modules -- it literally does nothing.

Comment: I have just given a code snippet. Now, I have the clear understanding of the localparam assignment from your explanation. It's to set 'p' number of bits of lp to 1.

Comment: BTW, this code will not work if P==0 because it is illegal to have a 0-width expression. See section _6.24.1 Casting Operator_ in the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). A better way to write this is `lp = (2**p)-1`

Comment: Also, I believe that some verilog parsers do not allow expressions in front of the apostrophe and are limited to literal constants.